# using preg_match for get value between two tag

Tags: php, html, preg-match

i try to get value between html tag :

```
preg_match(/<span class=\"value\">(.*)<\/span>/i', $file_string, $title);
```

html :

```
<p class="upc">
   <label>UPC/EAN/ISBN:</label> 
    <span class="value">746775319571</span>
</p>
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: refer it http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/all_about_html_tags.htm

Answer (score 3):

You do not parse HTML with regular expressions, but use [php DOM extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead:

```
$html = '<p class="upc">
   <label>UPC/EAN/ISBN:</label> 
    <span class="value">746775319571</span>
</p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$spans = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');

if ($spans->length > 0) {
    echo $spans->item(0)->nodeValue; // outputs 746775319571
}
```

Online demo: http://ideone.com/9W8gsv

If having a particular class value is a required constraint, then you can either perform the check manually by iterating over `$spans` and checking `class` attribute (using [`DOMElement::getAttributeNode`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattributenode.php)). Or using [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) instead.

Either way, I'm leaving it as a homework, because we all know how satisfactory it is to solve issues yourself!

Comment: Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 226 in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo\index.php on line 22

Comment: @user3901635: okay, so?

Comment: if any solution then tell me

Comment: @user3901635: please check the link I gave. I provided it with purpose.

Comment: hello friend, i try online with my code : http://ideone.com/r63HS9 but generate error

Comment: @user3901635: have you tried to read the first error message? It explicitly states why it happened. Please, at least give some effort in solving **your** issues. We are here to not write code for you for free. Thank you.

Comment: sorry friend, I am not familiar with DomElement

Comment: @user3901635: the error on your link on ideone has nothing to do with DOM. If you read it - you would know that.